# Delete "Who succeeds when a King dies leaving a daughter and a son in-utero?"

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I recently asked this question: [In the Commonwealth realms, who succeeds when a King dies leaving a daughter and a son in-utero?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/who-succeeds-when-a-king-dies-leaving-a-daughter-and-a-son-in-utero)

When I asked it, I was not aware that the laws had actually changed, rendering my question moot. However, its been voted up and has lots of comments.

Should interesting-but-moot questions like mine be deleted?

Comment: I don't see any reason to delete the question. It's on topic, answerable and - as shown by the upvotes - quite interesting. "laws changed, here's what the current law says" is a perfectly valid answer, someone just needs to post it.

Comment: Actually "The laws have changed" is a valid answer to the question, which should be made and accepted.  Feel free to self-answer if no one else has.

Answer (score 4):

It's on topic, interesting and as Yannis says, interesting. There is no reason I see to delete it.